# Itertools combination with index

Tags: python, list, indexing, python-itertools

Say I have `dlist=[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8],[9,10]]`. And I want to have combination of two lists with their indexes together.

Desired output is

```
[[0,1],[[1,2],[3,4]]], [[0,2],[[1,2],[5,6]]] and so on..
```

following code creates

`clist.append([list(itertools.combinations(list(enumerate(dlist)), 2))])`

```
[((0, [1, 2]), (1, [3, 4])), ((0, [1, 2]), (2, [5, 6])),....
```

instead..

Comment: Where do the `0`s come from? are you subtracting from each element...?

Comment: that is index of [1,2] in dlist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost there. Just need to convert your `clist` to desired format.
`itertools.combinations( enumerate(dlist), 2)` will return iterator of combinations in format `((index_number_of_sub_arr1, sub_arr1), (index_number_of_sub_arr2, sub_arr2))`. 
You just need to walk over iterator in convert it to your format `[[index_number_of_sub_arr1, index_number_of_sub_arr2],[sub_arr1, sub_arr2]]`.

```
# this is like your current clist (iterator)
tmp_list = itertools.combinations( enumerate(dlist), 2) 

# convertion to desired format
clist = [ [[idx1, idx2], [arr1,arr2]] for ((idx1, arr1),(idx2,arr2)) in tmp_list ]
```